# Is it using RMI for invoking the web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am new to web services and studing Jax-WS web services these days. I created a little web service and host it in tomcat server and created a **java web service client for accessing the service as well**. But I am having a little confusion in the web service client, because in the client we generate a stub for accessing the service.

Here is it using RMI for invoking the web service???

According to my knowledge tomcat is a web container and it is not supporting for RMI.

I searched this through the internet and I was unable to find the clear answer. Can anybody please simply explain me how does it happen.

If the tomcat is not supporting to RMI how does it invoke the web service. **I have this confusion since it uses the stub that we generated using wsimport command.**

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is it using RMI for invoking the web service???

Http. The web service client would create a http request (just like how a browser does when you request a url), convert your request object to an xml payload and invoke your service end point. Different vendors of JAX-WS may use different implementations, but it is usually some form of [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) is a popular package to create Http connections from a java program.

Comment: Is it means it doesn't use the RMI and it's all about sending the request to web service at the Service Endpoint by using the url ?

Comment: I am really appreciate If you can answer to this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040047/where-does-the-generated-wsdl-file-located