# Where is the generated WSDL file located?

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I am new to web services and studing Jax-WS web services these days. I created a little web service and hosted it in Tomcat server. I have first created the web service classes and generated the WSDL. I have created the project using eclipse IDE.

When we create the web service class first and try to generate the WSDL using the class where is the generated WSDL file located?

I want to know whether the file is generated at the deployment time or is it located in exact place in the WAR file after generating ????

Can anybody please help me to clarify this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check webservice running status

```
http://localhost:8080/<Your project name>/services/<Webservice class name>
```

To locate wsdl file

```
http://localhost:8080/<Your project name>/services/<Webservice class name>?wsdl
```

Comment: Thanks... But I meant without accessing it through the url how can we find it inside a folder like the web.xml is in the WEB-INF folder..

Comment: wsdl file should contains WEB-INF -> WSDL folder if not right your web service class file and create new webservice

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your jax-ws provider. For example if you are using the jwsc ant task or tool that is used by weblogic, the wsdl is generated when the web service is deployed (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13750/anttasks.htm#WSREF126)

If you are using the [reference implementation](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.8/docs/ch04.html#wsgen-overview), then you can specify that the wsdl be generated at compile time using the 'genwsdl' switch. The wsdl itself will be generated at the location specified in the 'resourcedestdir' attribute.

Comment: Sir can you explain it bit more... I uses JAX-WS RI. I uses eclipse ide and tomcat server for developing the service. In this scenario is it created at the time it deploy the SEI ....?

Comment: I have not created web services using eclipse and so I cannot comment authoritatively. This - http://www.java2blog.com/2013/03/soap-web-service-example-in-java-using.html may help. It shows that the wsdl is generated inside a folder called wsdl inside the webcontent folder of your project.